# Java Insert Data Into Database by Timestamp

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am using the Netbeans IDE and using Derby for my database.

I am trying to insert a row of data into a table in my database, but I want the data that I insert to be ordered by timestamp.

So, for instance, I already have 3 rows of data in the table of data (rows 1, 2, and 3). When I insert a new row of data with a timestamp that comes before the others, I want it to automatically  move to row 1 and for the previous row 1,2,3 to all be shifted down by 1.

I tried for my SQL statement:

```
"INSERT INTO WAITLIST (HOLIDAY, TIME, CUSTOMER) values (?,?,?) ORDER BY TIME"
```

By the way, WAITLIST is the table name and HOLIDAY, TIME, and CUSTOMER are the column names. That SQL statement didn't work as I got an error for the ORDER BY syntax.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a Database, not an excel-table. you sort the items when you select them. There is no such Syntax order by in an Insert Statement

Comment: I haven't seen `insert order by` commands! just insert data and `select order by`.

Comment: But doesn't the select statement store the results in a resultset? I want it changed in the actual table.

Comment: with insert, you do save it in the database. with select you load them from the database. so if you want your get information from the database ordered by date use a select statement. this as you said returns a resultset. with the resultset you can display your information in a table e.g.

Comment: The actual order in which the data is stored doesn't matter, is the order in which you retrieve it what matters, that is your select statement's order by clause.